# Written the below command in oracle sql and getting the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis how to fix this?

Tags: oracle

```
create table EMPLOYEES
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
    EMAIL VARCHAR2(25),
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    HIRE_DATE DATE(7),
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10),
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    COMISSION_PCT NUMBER(2,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

[This is what I want to create (constraints and other information)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5BhU.png)

Answer (score 0):

date datatype doesn't accept the length so no need to write date(7) just simply write date and after you run the command desc EMPLOYEES; it will show you that the length of date is by default 7.

```
    create table EMPLOYEES(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    COMISSION_PCT NUMBER(2,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4) DEFAULT NULL
    );
```